# Java set disable color of a JButton on OSX

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Hi I'm trying to have multiple buttons with disabled text color different from button to button.
I have made it in windows but not work on osx

```
class TestButton{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setBounds(0,0,600,600);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton b = new JButton();
        b.setBounds(0,0,80,80);
        f.add(b);

        b.setUI(new MetalButtonUI() {
            protected Color getDisabledTextColor() {
                return Color.RED;
            }
        });
        
        b.setEnabled(false);
        
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I have seen that while in windows b.getUI returns MetalButtonUI, osx returns com.apple.laf.AquaButtonUI but tha assess is restricted.
There is a way to make it?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want your UI components to look exactly the same on all operating systems, make your own set with 'fixed' UI. Use this idom:

```
public class CustomButton extends JButton {
  public CustomButton() {
    setUI(new CustomButtonUI());
  }

  @Override
  public void updateUI() {
    // fixed UI
  }

  private static class CustomButtonUI extends BasicButtonUI {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Extend from Basic or Metal UI classes.

By overriding the udpateUI method with an empty body, you sidestep the pluggable look & feel mechanism.

Comment: ok, but the button is not visible, if enabled there is no animation of the button ecc... should I @Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) and remake all buttons properties?

Comment: It's usually either or. Either you want the look & feel (including animations) of the operating system, or you want to roll your own. Sometimes you can get away with just changing a few properties, but you will never have a guarantee how each look & feel will handle it (or completely ignore it).